# Could not update Firebase version to 11.4.2

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to upgrade the version of Firebase to 11.4.2
I made the following changes in my project:
in project gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and my module gradle file:

```
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2"
```

I am getting this error when I build the project:

> Error:Could not GET
>   'https://maven.google.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/11.4.2/firebase-messaging-11.4.2.pom'.
>   Received status code 403 from server: Authentication required

Comment: It works, may be there was a issue with the connection

Comment: Proxy is configured with IDE and gradle
in fact firebase-10.0.4 is downloaded and i can build the app

Comment: Your proxy is probably causing problems.

Comment: is there any way to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the problem:

- Download Android Studio `3.0` version
- Update the Gradle plugin to classpath `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'`
- Update gradle wrapper version of the project to: `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.2-all.zip`
- The build tools must be at least `26.0.2`

if you are working with proxy, you must configure your project gradle.

Answer (score 0):

With new Android Studio 3.0 the error list suggests a "link" "Add Google Maven repository and sync project", which will change build.grade (Module:...) repositories to:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    **google()**
}
```

that fixed my problem.